# How to make a button Stay where it is when text is changing length

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So i Have been trying to make this button stay in the same position but when ever the text changes its length the button always moves 
i have tried removing the row and column values that doesn't work
i have tried changing the row and column values that doesn't work
so i don't really know what to do

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.title('ab')
win.config(bg='blue')
win.geometry('200x100')
i = 0
def changetext():
    global i
    i = i + 1
    if i == 1:
        lbl.config(text='a')
    if i == 2:
        lbl.config(text='ab')
    if i == 3:
        lbl.config(text='abc')
    if i == 4:
        lbl.config(text='abcd')
    if i == 5:
        lbl.config(text='abcde')

lbl = Label(win,text='111111111111', font=("Courier", 9))
lbl.grid(row=1,column=2)
btn = Button(win,text='u', command =changetext)
btn.grid(row=2,column=2)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `width` option of `Label` to fix the label width.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: Try `lbl = Label(win,text='111111111111', font=("Courier", 9), width=20)`.  Adjust the width value to whatever suit your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the button (or pretty much any widget for that matter), you can define its width.

```
lbl = Label(win, width= 20, text = '111111111111', font = ("Courier",9))

btn = Button(win, width = 20, text = 'u', command = changetext)
```